# Redux in ng2/typescript, having trouble using combineReducers

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

I have a Angular 2 app I am playing around with. When I run it, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/store/store.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/benhernandez/angular-force/src/app/store/store.ts (10,14):
Exported variable 'rootReducer' has or is using name 'Action' from external module "/Users/benhernandez/angular-force/node_modules/redux/index" but cannot be named.)
at _checkDiagnostics (/Users/benhernandez/angular-force/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:115:15)
at /Users/benhernandez/angular-force/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:140:17
@ ./src/app/store/index.ts 1:0-69
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/app/index.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi main
```

The code on line 10 is:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers<State>({
  twiglet: twiglet.twigletReducer,
  view: view.viewReducer,
});
```

Any help is appreciated. I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out my problem, angular wasn't including the Action from redux, changed my import statement from

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
```

to

```
import { Action, combineReducers } from 'redux';
```

and that fixed it.